# web services used by network devices or by server

Tags: webserver

I know what is meant by web services but **I was not able to find any web services for the network devices or for the webserver..!**
Sorry for asking this question it may be stupid but I didn't find any answer on google.
Thanks

Comment: So you went looking for a web service and you didn't find one?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question.  Rather, it is about finding web services for a network device or webserver.

Comment: I've found webservices. But i dont' find webservices related to network devices or may be I'm not able to understand this.